# Nodejs result and error handling - 'TypeError: callback is not a function

Tags: node.js, error-handling, method-call

I am writing a method that returns either a result or an error.

```
myMethod.methodName = (param1, param2, param3, error, callback) => {
    try {
        myDB.findOne({ param1: value}, function (err, result) {
            if (err) {
                throw(err);
            }
            if (result) {              
              callback(result);
        });

    } catch (e) {
        error(e);
    }
};
```

From calling function, I'm calling it as below:

```
myExport.data.methodName(param1, param2, param3, (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log("Result error:", err);
        }
        if (result) {
            console.log('result : ', result);
        }
    });
```

Here I am facing an error : 'TypeError: callback is not a function

How can I implement a method call that return error or result And how to handle it?

Comment: Would the downvoter provide a reason, please?

Comment: I see you've reversed the upvote and accept - do you have a problem with the answer?

Comment: Well, for the last 5 days I am waiting for you to answer the similar question of mine, did you find any issue with my question so that you downvote it?

Comment: How did you conclude that I downvoted it? That downvote isn't mine.

Comment: Sorry. Rectified my mistake. But how do I know who has downvoted me? Any suggestion would be helpful. 
Thanks.

Comment: It's not possible to know unless the downvoter volunteers with the info. Sorry. A lot of my answers do get downvoted without a reason - as with here I just add a comment and leave it at that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`methodName()` takes 5 parameters and 5th one is the callback. You're passing callback as the 4th argument when calling the method, so inside `methodName()` callback is actually null. Hence the error.

Your caller is correct. Change your method definiton like so:

```
myMethod.methodName = (param1, param2, param3, callback) => {
    try {
        myDB.findOne({ param1: value}, function (err, result) {
            if (err) {
                return callback(err);
            }
            return callback(null, result);
            //rest of the code as-is
            ...
```